# Split a string at the thrid occurance from end in js

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

> 01-08-2011_11-08-20113-My Id-MY Name-1.tif

I want to split from end of the string at the third occurrence of ("-") as at the beginning of the string the length might change. this is what i want is:

> My Id-MY Name-1.tif

I don't want to use `slice` and `pop`. I only want to use `split`, `lastindexof`, `substring`, and `indexof`.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: `split`, `slice` and `join` is going to do this in 1 line. Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 2):

```
myStr.replace(/^.*-([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)$/, '$1')
```

This captures everything between the last three dashes and replaces the whole string with just that part.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine :)

Comment: I finaly got the soultion. I used this type = name[name.size()-1];
sName =name[name.size()-2]; sIdNo = name[name.size()-3]; to get the last three array element in the string

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do it - as I'm pretty new to js, but the below does work. This is based on your request not to use splice and pop.

```
var input = "01-08-2011_11-08-20113-My Id-MY Name-1.tif";
var sc = input.split("-");
var r1 = sc[sc.length-1]
var r2 = sc[sc.length-2]
var r3 = sc[sc.length-3]
var rtn = [r3,r2,r1].join("-")
alert (rtn) //returns: My Id-MY Name-1.tif
```